# Нужна ли запятая между прилагательными?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прилагательные, однородные-члены

В этот сказочный(,) мокрый день.

(Не знаю поможет ли, но - действо происходит под водой, русалка присутствует.)

Comment: Трудно понять. каким образом эти две характеристики оказались рядом. Возможно, контекст оправдывает такое соседство. Желательно в таких вопросах приводить контекст.

Answer (score 1):

**В этот сказочный, мокрый день...**

Запятая  ставится между **однородными** прилагательными, если они раскрывают одну тему. Не зная текста, здесь трудно определить семантику отношений, но можно провести **формальный анализ**.

**Сказочный** ― это относительное по происхождению прилагательное, которое может переходит в качественное со значением "удивительный, небывалый, редкостный".

И если прилагательное стоит **на первом месте,** то оно является именно **качественным** и, скорее всего, находится в однородных отношениях с прилагательным "мокрый". Сравнить: **в этот сказочный, солнечный день.**